# SonarQube does not analyze files after upgrade from 4.2 to 4.3

Tags: sonarqube

After the upgrade of sonarqube 4.2 to 4.3 i'm getting this message:

> 13:15:18.349 WARN  - File '%s' is ignored. It is not located in module basedir '%s'.
>   [repeated for (assuming) all my c# files]
>
> 13:15:18.349 INFO  - 0 files indexed

We run sonar from msbuild, and pass in (among others) the command line argument:
  -D sonar.sources="../../Source/"

Which is correctly resolved the full path is can see in the logging

the output displays

> C:\projects\myproject\build\Tools\SonarRunner.2.3\bin..
>
> SonarQube Runner 2.3
>
> Java 1.7.0_51 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
>
> Windows 8 6.2 amd64
>
> INFO: Runner configuration file: 
>   C:\projects\project\build\Tools\SonarRunner.2.3\bin..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
>
> INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
>
> INFO: Default locale: "en_GB", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
>
> INFO: Work directory: C:\projects\project\Build\Scripts.sonar
>
> INFO: SonarQube Server 4.3
>
> 13:13:43.706 INFO  - Load batch settings
>
> 13:13:43.924 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\username.sonar\cache
>
> 13:15:16.155 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
>
> 13:15:16.356 INFO  - Base dir: C:\projects\project\Build\Scripts
>
> 13:15:16.356 INFO  - Working dir: C:\projects\project\Build\Scripts.sonar
>
> 13:15:16.356 INFO  - Source dirs: C:\projects\project\Source
>
> 13:15:16.356 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_GB
>
> 13:15:16.356 INFO  - Index files
>
> 13:15:16.358 INFO  - Excluded tests:
>
> 13:15:16.358 INFO  -   **/*.IntegrationTests/***/.*
>
> 13:15:16.358 INFO  -   **/*.UnitTests/***/.*
>
> 13:15:17.287 WARN  - File '%s' is ignored. It is not located in module basedi
>     r '%s'.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner) may help (update: url no longer available: [Alternative](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code))

"Module base directory can be specified for special cases
By default, the module base directory is guessed from the module identifier (like in the examples above). But it can be redefined using the sonar.projectBaseDir property."

Comment: Thank you. I set the project.home & sonar.projectBaseDir to my soure folder. Still using the 2.3 runner now. 
Also the full path was required, relative didn't work, and had to change c:\path to c:/path. 

Also removed -D project.settings, since it is listed as not compatible with these options.

Comment: Do you have the latest link? The link present in the answer is outdated

Comment: @SamuelAlexander
This is the best page i could find:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code

Comment: All those links are broken

Comment: both the links not working, any updated link available to refer or even better if you can post a solution here itself