# Sonar scanner 3.1.0 via TFS Server 2018 breaks on finalize step, no analysable projects were found

Tags: c#, sonarqube

For all .NET Framework and .NET Core projects in our TFS server 2018 the sonar scan does not finish scan after updatet to version 3.1.0.

We have the following build configuration in TFS server 2018, for a .NET Framework project:
[Build configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CGzc.png)

The build breaks on the complete analyse step with the following error:

> 2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z ##[error]No analysable projects were
>   found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed. Check the build
>   summary report for details. 2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z Generation of
>   the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube
>   analysis. 2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z 10:28:19.543  Creating a
>   summary markdown file... 2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z
>
> ### [error]10:28:19.543  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1 2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected
>
> exit code received from batch file: 1 2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z
>
> ### [debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
>
> 2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z    at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z ##[debug]The build was not triggered by a
>   Pull Request, not processing code analysis comments
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z ##[debug]Invoke - Get-TaskVariable cmdlet
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.5905262Z ##[debug]Variable read:
>   MSBuild.SonarQube.Internal.IncludeFullReport = true
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.6061603Z ##[debug]Invoke - Get-TaskVariable cmdlet
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.6061603Z ##[debug]Variable read:
>   MSBuild.SonarQube.Internal.ServerVersion = 
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.6217771Z ##[debug]Calling InvokeGetRestMethod
>   "/api/server/version"  2018-01-16T09:28:19.6374047Z ##[debug]Invoke -
>   Get-TaskVariable cmdlet 2018-01-16T09:28:19.6374047Z ##[debug]Variable
>   read: MSBuild.SonarQube.HostUrl = https://sonar.MyOrganisation.nl/
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.6530505Z ##[debug]Invoke - Get-TaskVariable cmdlet
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.6530505Z ##[debug]Variable read:
>   MSBuild.SonarQube.ServerUsername = ********
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.6530505Z ##[debug]Invoke - Get-TaskVariable cmdlet
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.6530505Z ##[debug]Variable read:
>   MSBuild.SonarQube.ServerPassword =  2018-01-16T09:28:19.6842912Z
>
> ### [debug]GET https://sonar.MyOrganisation.nl/api/server/version with 0-byte payload 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7155095Z ##[debug]received 11-byte
>
> response of content type text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.7323972Z ##[debug]Processed:
>
> ### vso[task.setvariable variable=MSBuild.SonarQube.Internal.ServerVersion;]6.7.1.35068
>
> 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7323972Z  2018-01-16T09:28:19.7323972Z 
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.7323972Z ##[debug]The SonarQube server version is
>   6.7.1.35068 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7467772Z Waiting on the SonarQube server to finish processing in order to determine the quality gate
>   status. 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7467772Z  2018-01-16T09:28:19.7467772Z 
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.7467772Z ##[debug]Invoke - Get-TaskVariable cmdlet
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.7467772Z ##[debug]Variable read:
>   Agent.BuildDirectory = d:/_work\3 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7624290Z
>
> ### [debug]Could not find the task details file at d:/_work\3.sonarqube\out.sonar\report-task.txt
>
> 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7936587Z
>
> ### [error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube
>
> server version is lower than 5.3 - for more details see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407 --->
>   System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the
>   analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version
>   is lower than 5.3 - for more details see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.7936587Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue
>   type=error;]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot
>   determine if the analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube
>   server version is lower than 5.3 - for more details see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407 --->
>   System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the
>   analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version
>   is lower than 5.3 - for more details see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.7936587Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   --- 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7936587Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable
>   input) 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7936587Z    at
>   System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace
>   rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke) 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7936587Z    at
>   System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace
>   rsToUse, Boolean isSync) 2018-01-16T09:28:19.7936587Z    at
>   System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1
>   input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.7936587Z    at
>   System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1
>   input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>   2018-01-16T09:28:19.7936587Z    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.VSTSPowerShellHost.Main(String[]
>   args) 2018-01-16T09:28:19.8092817Z
>
> ### [error]LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe completed with return code: -1. 2018-01-16T09:28:19.8092817Z ##[section]Finishing: Complete the
>
> SonarQube analysis

I have checked the build log in debug mode, but i can't see anything wrong.

Temp location with the full log with debug mode:
https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ADdDbeYD4oxJ9NA&id=5A1F84872B7BA3C1%21952&cid=5A1F84872B7BA3C1

Note that i have replaced my organisation name with: myorganiation and the project name with MyProject in the log.

Comment: The csc.exe entries in the build logs should specify /analyzer parameters, but they don't, although they do have the expected /additionalfile setting.
* are you using a hosted agent or a custom agent?
* could you run the analysis again with verbose output? Set the Additional Settings in the "Prepare" step to

/d:sonar.verbose=true

Comment: Thx for looking. We are using custom agents with Visual Studio 2017. I have updated the logs in the share where i have used /d:sonar.verbose=true

Comment: Thanks. I'd have expected to see more log entries in the Prepare step e.g. about analysers being downloaded. The Prepare step will have generated a file in agent working folder called SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml (e.g. C:\agent\_work\[xxx]\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml). Could you share a sanitized version of that file please? (there won't be any secrets in it, but there might be other settings you want to obscure).
Also, which version of the C# plugin do you have installed on your SonarQube server?

Comment: I don't have enough rights on the company sonar server, but i will check after the weekend.

Comment: Our C# plugin in Sonar is version  6.7.1. I have tried a few things myself. When downgrading the scanner on the build agent manualy: 'D:\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeScannerMsBuildBegin_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\3.1.0\SonarQubeScannerMsBuild' with 'sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656', the scanner works again.  

When i open the quality profiles on sonar, i see that the C# profile is not updated for 3 years. I'm going to try to update the profile later this day, maybey that is the solution.

Comment: Updating the C# quality profile did't work. I have uploaded C:\agent_work[xxx]\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConf‌​ig.xml to the share for you. I hope you see the problem.

Comment: The SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml file looks ok. It's interesting that downgrading the scanner manually worked, although I don't know what at the moment.

Downgrading the VSTS task to version 2.* would use version 2.3 of the scanner for MSBuild, although I can't remember what other changes there were between version 3 and 2.

Could you upload the generated ruleset please? (d:\_work\3\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeRoslyn-cs.ruleset)

I'm not sure what else to suggest, short of running MSBuild with full diagnostic output which will be extremely verbose.

Comment: Version 4.0.1 has come out, i will try to use this one first later today or tommorow. If this works i will let you know.

Comment: It is working! I have configured a build agent on my laptop and then the analyze works. After comparing logs a long time i have found it. And this topic helpt me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696251/sonarqube-does-not-analyze-files-after-upgrade-from-4-2-to-4-3/23708680#23708680.

It was de working path for the build agent. We had it configured like this: "workFolder": "d:/_work" but the correct path must be: "workFolder": "d:\\_work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working! I have configured a build agent on my laptop and then the analyze works. After comparing logs a long time i have found it. And this topic helpt me stackoverflow.com/questions/23696251/…. It was de working path for the build agent. We had it configured like this: "workFolder": "d:/_work" but the correct path must be: "workFolder": "d:\\_work"