# SonarQube scan runs but doesn’t generate any results

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, sonarqube-scan, software-quality

I’m running a SonarQube scan for the first time. It’s the CE version, 8.3.1.

I have SQ running on a server at 192.168.56.111. My development workstation is on 192.168.0.11. There are no network problems.

Since I’m new to SQ, I’m trying to keep it as basic as possible. I’m using the sample HelloWorld in https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/blob/master/sonarqube-scanner-maven/maven-basic/src/main/java/com/acme/basic/

I’m not using Git. Just saving the HelloWorld project to the local hard drive

The source code is at /opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/

The scanner is at /opt/sonarqube/scanner/sonar-scanner-4.4.0.2170-linux/bin

Here’s a copy of the properties file. I’m using the same file whether or not I put it in the scanner’s conf directory or the application workspace… I’ve seen different webpages that say it goes in either spot:

```
sonar.host.url=http://192.168.56.111:9000

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.projectKey=com.mycompany.app:my-app

sonar.scm.disabled=True

sonar.sources=/opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app

sonar.login=73a9a7ab66a335d0d83aee813d576e184934a336
```

When I run sonar-scanner and then go check the results, Projects | Name | Overview, it says "The main branch has no lines of code".

Question #1: If sonar.scm.disabled=True is in the props file, how can this error happen? I also went to the project settings in the SQ server and disabled the SCM sensor there too. Same results.

Question #2: I noticed in the terminal output, it said .java files are being ignored. So I changed the sonar.sources property to where the class files are at: /opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/target/classes/com/mycompany/app/. Same results. What should the sonar.sources property be? Does SQ work on the java files or the class files?

The results say “No Issues. Hooray!”. So I added this but of ugliness to the sayHello method in the HelloWorld class:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024);
```

Question #3: Still no code issues. SQ should have flagged on the 1024 (as it’s less than 2048) size right?

==== Edit 23 August ====

Adding output from the terminal per @HernánAlarcón 's comment.

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonarqube/scanner/sonar-scanner-4.4.0.2170-linux/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.4.0.2170
INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/dogzilla/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonarqube/scanner/sonar-scanner-4.4.0.2170-linux/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 8.3.1
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=69ms
INFO: Server id: A7EE8CF2-AXMiwj91ZEnoz7IhXD_G
INFO: User cache: /home/dogzilla/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=36ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=86ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=7ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Project key: com.mycompany.app:my-app
INFO: Base dir: /opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/target/classes/com/mycompany/app
INFO: Working dir: /opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/target/classes/com/mycompany/app/.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'com.mycompany.app:my-app'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'com.mycompany.app:my-app' (done) | time=17ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=40ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=851ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
WARN: File '/opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/HelloWorld.java' is ignored. It is not located in project basedir '/opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/target/classes/com/mycompany/app'.
WARN: File '/opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/AppRunner.java' is ignored. It is not located in project basedir '/opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/target/classes/com/mycompany/app'.
WARN: File '/opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/sonar-scanner.properties' is ignored. It is not located in project basedir '/opt/workspace/eclipse/java/my-app/target/classes/com/mycompany/app'.
INFO: 0 files indexed
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module com.mycompany.app:my-app
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=38ms
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/home/dogzilla/.sonar/cache/54f6535c111cefad0fb6a09ba3e61922/sonar-javascript-plugin.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily]
INFO: No CSS, PHP, HTML or VueJS files are found in the project. CSS analysis is skipped.
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
INFO: SCM Publisher is disabled
INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 0 files
INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Analysis report generated in 70ms, dir size=77 KB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 12ms, zip size=9 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 35ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://192.168.56.111:9000/dashboard?id=com.mycompany.app%3Amy-app
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://192.168.56.111:9000/api/ce/task?id=AXQeYMFVCyJo7mZCTWSk
INFO: Analysis total time: 2.802 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 3.561s
INFO: Final Memory: 6M/37M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you show us how are you running the scanner and what is its output?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Will do... editing the original post with the info.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567128/sonar-runner-doesnt-index-any-files) solve your question?

Comment: It does.  I added sonar.projectBaseDir to the properties file rather than sonar.sources and it works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay @HernánAlarcón, how do I give you credit for the answer?  Your responses have been comments rather than posts?